# Simple explanation needed why delegate does not pass when placed in this section of code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to pass a users' email address to another ViewController via a delegate when the user has successfully logged in.

The snippet of code in question (marked *) works fine where it is and the data is passed successfully.  However, at this point the user has not successfully logged in, therefore I would rather insert the snippet where the /**** is, a little further down.

However it does work when in that position.  Why is that?  (I am new to Swift)

Thanks

```
 @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
{

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

    if (userPassword!.isEmpty || userEmail!.isEmpty) { return; }

// send user data to server side


    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/userLogin.php");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

               // spinningActivity!.hide(true)


               if(error != nil)
                {

                    //Display an alert message
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]


                   *if self.delegate != nil {
                        self.delegate?.userLoggedIn(data: userEmail! )
                    }

                    // retrieve login details and check to see if all ok

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                        if(returnValue != "error")
                        {
                           /**** if self.delegate != nil {
                                self.delegate?.userLoggedIn(data: userEmail! )
                            } ****/

                            UserDefaults.set(UserDefaults.standard)(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

                            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
                            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage!)
                            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                            appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainPageNav 

                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


                        } else {
                            // display an alert message
                            let userMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    }
                } catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }


        }



    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? As far as the delegate code itself, there is no general reason why it shouldn't work in the second place if it works in the first. I see that the second call (which you say doesn't work) is nested within 2 conditionals though. if `json` is nil or if `returnValue` is `error`, then it won't work. Have you set breakpoints to see what code path is actually being taken? As a side note, you don't actually need to check to see if the delegate is nil before calling the method, the call itself handles the optional unwrap.

Comment: when I say it doesn't work - I mean that no data is passed.   Why does it not work in the nested conditionals?  My reason for wanting it there is because at that point the email & password has been matched and the user is logged in.  So I am wanting to copy the user's email address to the ViewController so I can use it in the other Views.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at the place you are calling the delegate to see if that code is actually being reached? I suspect one of those conditionals is evaluating to false and skipping your code.

Comment: I didn't.  Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: UPDATE:  I took out the 'if self.delegate != nil' and left the ' self.delegate?.userLoggedIn(data: userEmail! )' and it works??

But why is that, as self.delegate must != nil for it to work??